# indexeddb oncomplete not writing to disk

Tags: firefox, indexeddb, microsoft-edge

We are seeing a problem with trx.oncomplete where the data is not being written to the db on disk. FireFox has an explanation of what they did that is causing this problem here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBTransaction/oncomplete

It seems that windows/edge is also having the same issue. Basically, there is no guarantee that your app will have data written to the database, if/when the user decides to kill or power down the device/app. We've even tried waiting up to 15 minutes before shutting down in some cases and haven't seen the data written. For me I'd always want to ensure that a data write completes and is committed.

Are there other solutions for data persistence, or enhancements to the IndexedDB beyond FF (only) experimental add...